# NGINX command not found

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

NGINX was built from source using the latest stable build on a debian 9 server. sudo nginx command cannot be found. The NGINX install is located in /usr/local/nginx. How can I configure my server to follow the standard sudo nginx [command] rules? I have tried adding PATH=/usr/sbin/:$PATH which did not work since NGINX is not located in sbin. Thanks

Comment: Try run command `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nginx/`

Comment: If you run `which nginx`, what do you see?

Comment: I ram the export command then which nginx and i get this response: /usr/local/nginx//nginx

Comment: A double `//`? Anyway, you need either rename the directory if that's the case, and then make sure you sent the `export PATH` correctly corresponding to where your nginx is installed

Comment: What is the output of `find /usr -type f -name "nginx"`?

Comment: The output is `/usr/local/nginx/nginx` - not sure why there is a double `//`. Any way to edit the path?

Answer (score 20):

Run echo `$PATH` Does it contain `/usr/local/sbin`?

If not then add `PATH=/usr/sbin/:$PATH` to your .profile file.

Also, check that nginx is installed in `/usr/local/sbin`, by going into this directory.

If not then install it by using following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

Comment: This question really belongs on SuperUser, so I've added the following fully descriptive answer on a pre-existing question there - https://superuser.com/questions/662306/nginx-v-command-not-found/1509120#1509120